# How can an approximation ratio be less than 1?

Tags: algorithms, terminology, approximation

A question in my algorithms text-book requires that we,

> Describe an efficient $(1 - \frac{1}{k})$ -approximation algorithm for this
>   problem.

It is my understanding that $(1 - \frac{1}{k})$ being $p(n)$ is the approximation ratio and that an approximate solution differs from an optimal solution by a factor of $p(n)$. In that case, if $p(n)< 1$ wouldn't the approximation be better than optimal?

How can the approximation ratio be less than $1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For maximization problems, if the optimal solution is $O^*$ and the worst possible approximate solution is $O$, then the standard way is to consider $O^*/O$ as the approximation ratio. But in some text books, the ratio $O/O^*$ is considered for both minimization and maximization problems and it causes the ratio to be smaller than 1.

You may refer to [Approximation Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_algorithm) for more details.

Comment: Conclusio: check the definition *in that book*.

Comment: agree with Raphael. Definitions change. Sometimes $\epsilon$-approximation means finding an answer which is within $(1\pm \epsilon) Opt$.